# Bridge access attempt with wrong secret token, possibly from malicious code. Disabling exec() bridge! error message on phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm developing an app for Android with PhoneGap and I have that error when I tried to execute a `localstorage` code:

```
Error: Security_err:dom exception 18
```

I saw in any post that error is a because use `localstorage` without devideready but I'm using that, and the rarest message is on the console debug:

```
 Bridge access attempt with wrong secret token, possibly from malicious code. Disabling exec() bridge!
```

Im using document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false); im not using code for localstorage with out devideready.

edit: code

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false);
var db = "";
//initDB(); //añadido
function initDB() {
    try {
        if(!window.openDatabase)
            alert('not supported');
        else{

            var shortName = 'Pictogramas';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'PhoneGap Pictogramas Database';
            var maxSize = 9999999999;   // en bytes
            db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
        if(e == INVALID_STATE_ERR)
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        else
            alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
        return;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Update the question with your code

Comment: You have no localStorage code there